# My Custom Authorize Attribute always fire, even without setting in global.asax and Attributes in Controllers/Actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have a Custom Authorize Attribute that always fire. I remove the configuration in global.asax and have no attributes in controllers/actions. Why?

```
public class ValidatePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private AuthorizationContext _context;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        base.OnAuthorization(context);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = false;

        //Use _context here
        ...

        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

My Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogActionAttribute());

        //ValidatePermissionFilterProvider validatePermissionProvider = new ValidatePermissionFilterProvider();

        //validatePermissionProvider.Add("Login", "Index");
        //validatePermissionProvider.Add("Erro", "*");

        //FilterProviders.Providers.Add(validatePermissionProvider);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Usuario", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ViewModelValidations";

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return DependencyResolverFactory.Instance.Kernel;
    }
}
```

**Discover the problem:**

With answer of @DarinDimitrov I discover the problem, I'm using Ninject to inject a dependcy in my Filter, this is causing to fire in every Controller:

```
public class ApplicationServicesModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.BindFilter<ValidatePermissionAttribute>(FilterScope.First, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a custom attribute doesn't do anything. There must be some code that is registering it. It could be either registered as global action filter, you could have a controller/action decorated with it or you might have your dependency injection framework which registers it as a global action filter. Right click on the `ValidatePermissionAttribute` and search where this class is being used. Normally VS will show you where you have registered it.

Comment: I know that, because of this I'm confusing, I'll post the rest of the code.

Comment: @Acaz Souza, search in your solution. There is no point in posting some code that doesn't contain the attribute. I suspect that there must be some registration left somewhere. Maybe it's registered somewhere in your Ninject modules. Here's what you can do as well: Remove this class from the project. You will see where it booms and yuo will know where exactly you are registering it :-)

Comment: Thanks man, you save me. Is my DI Container that i'm using to inject a dependcy in my Filter. See update.

Comment: @Acaz Souza, glad you could find the issue. Is there something else you would like to ask or maybe you could close this question?

Comment: @Darin - already upvoted your previous comment, wish I could do it 2x. Good approach, to paraphrase the Pragmatic Programmer, "fail big, otherwise you'll just FAIL!"

Answer (score 0):

If your controllers derive from a custom controller base class, you might want to check that to see if the attribute is present there also. You can also try to do a solution-wide Find Usages on the attribute name `ValidatePermissionAttribute` to see if there's somewhere you missed it.

EDIT: looking at your global.asax, I see that you are registering `LogActionAttribute` -- is it possible that attribute derives from your other custom authorization attribute? I would try removing *all* custom registrations and filters to see if the problem persists